# Selecionar area escpecificar no planilha excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou com a tabela abaixo na foto, e gostaria de criar um gráfico empilhado de area baseado nos benchmarks (valores das colunas). Estou o usando o seguinte código

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim planilhaB As Worksheet
Dim rng   As range

Set planilhaB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha2")

planilhaB.range("A1").Select
planilhaB.range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
planilhaB.range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set rng = Selection

End Sub
```

Mas ela acaba selecionando também a coluna Total do Dia. Não quero fazer referencia as celulas pq pode ser que sejam adicionados novas colunas no futuro, antes da coluna Total do Dia.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usei o seguinte código

```
planilhaB.Range("A1").Select
planilhaB.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select 
Dim rng as range
Dim rntLastColumn as range
Set Rng = planilhaBenchmark.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
Set rngLastColumn = Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Para não utilizar referências fixas e procurar pelo título, você pode utilizar a função do Excel [Match()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) e obter o número da coluna de um ponto inicial e um final.

Com isso, você consegue Selecionar os dados da tabela e poderá adicionar mais colunas entre a coluna inicial e a final.

#### Código

```
Dim planilhaB As Worksheet
Dim rng   As Range
Dim colunaData As Long, colunaTotalDoDia As Long

Set planilhaB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha2")

With planilhaB
    'Rows(1): para procurar o título na linha 1
    colunaData = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Data", .Rows(1), 0)
    colunaTotalDoDia = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Total do Dia", .Rows(1), 0)
    
    '.Cells(2: os dados iniciam na linha 2
    .Range(.Cells(2, colunaData), .Cells(2, colunaTotalDoDia - 1)).Select
    .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

End With
Set rng = Selection
```

> Obs.:
> [.Select/.Activate/.ActiveCell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/7690982)
> devem ser evitadas quase sempre (a não ser para ativar eventos ou
> outras ocasiões que é possível somente com Select).

Answer (score 2):

Se sua planinha não tiver outras áreas preenchidas descontínuas, seria razoavelmente simples usar `UsedRange`. Por exemplo:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim planilhaB As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngCelInicio As Range, rngCelFim As Range

    Set planilhaB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha2")

    With planilhaB
        Set rngCelInicio = .UsedRange.Cells(1, 1)
        Set rngCelFim = .UsedRange.Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)
        Set rng = Range(rngCelInicio, rngCelFim.Offset(0, -1))
    End With
End Sub
```